# Can a Framework Collision happen in a Swift SDK?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to develop a library, and then distribute it later as an SDK. In that library I am thinking of using a third party library.

What I am afraid of is if one of my users also include that same third party library. Would it still build? Otherwise, is there a way around this issue?

Note that I cannot use CocaoPods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can and will collide. You must not include a third-party library inside your library. You must have the app link both your library and your dependencies at the app layer. Tools like CocoaPods, Carthage, and SwiftPM simplify this. If you cannot use those, then you must provide instructions to your users of what libraries they must link.

Comment: What if I use SwiftPM and I am depending on a third library with version X.x, and my client wants to use a version Y.y in their app?

Comment: If Y.y is backward compatible with X.x, just make sure that you configure it to allow that full range of versions. If they are not compatible, then one or the other code bases will need to change to be compatible. As a rule, framework developers should absolutely minimize their use of additional non-OS dependencies, and where they do have a dependency, make sure that it is a very tight one (such that you would certainly have versions of your library that support every major version of the dependency). If it's not that tight a coupling, remove the direct dependency.